# How to get elements from a list that sum up to a number

Tags: java, arrays, list

For example of I have an array `numbers = [2,3,5,1,1,2,1]` and the `sum needed = 5`

How can I get the maximum number of elements that satisfy the sum 5 like  `[2,3] [5] [1,1,2,1]' and the answer should be the last one that I can get a total of 4 elements which is the maximum in this case

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please, attach code with your try and then the community should help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"maximum number of elements that satisfy the sum" means you want the sum of the smallest numbers (it is also obvious from the example).
So how about sorting the array? then it is a simple iteration to get the *first* combination that reaches the desired sum

Comment: Although sorting first is a nice approach, keep in mind that getting the first _combination_ might still not be very straight-forward. For the example the result is the first _prefix_ `[1,1,1,2]`, which is easy after the list is sorted. But let's say an input is `[3,1,5,2]` (sorted `[1,2,3,5]`) and the target sum is still `5`, then we'd have to skip the `1` to get `[2,3]` as our longest combination.